# docker run is stalling

Tags: asp.net, docker

I'm trying to run a docker image, which is essentially the default ASP.Net 6 default API:

```
docker run my-image-name --restart=aways -d -p 80:5111
```

I've tried a few different ways of running this, but it appears to always do the same thing.  First of all, whether I launch in detached mode or interactive, I get the following display:

```
{"EventId":14,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Now listening on: http://[::]:80","State":{"Message":"Now listening on: http://[::]:80","address":"http://[::]:80","{OriginalFormat}":"Now listening on: {address}"}}
{"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Application started. Press Ctrl\u002BC to shut down.","State":{"Message":"Application started. Press Ctrl\u002BC to shut down.","{OriginalFormat}":"Application started. Press Ctrl\u002BC to shut down."}}
{"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Hosting environment: Production","State":{"Message":"Hosting environment: Production","envName":"Production","{OriginalFormat}":"Hosting environment: {envName}"}}
{"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Content root path: /app","State":{"Message":"Content root path: /app","contentRoot":"/app","{OriginalFormat}":"Content root path: {contentRoot}"}}
```

It then seems to stall - I can't `ctrl-c`, nor can I attach to the process (it does show under `docker ps`). I also can't connect to the API:

```
http://localhost:5111/swagger
```

Just returns `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

My guess here is that there's something wrong with the dockerfile itself - however, it builds fine. The question I have is: how can I debug this in order to determine the error?

Comment: You could try to reorder the `docker run` parameters: `docker run --restart=aways -d -p 80:5111 my-image-name`

Comment: You should probably also fix the typo in the restart flag, - `always` instead of `aways`.

Comment: I still haven't got it to actually attach to the running port, but re-ordering the parameters did work - why?

Comment: Docker options like `-p` and `--restart` need to come before the image name.  Anything after the image name is interpreted as the command to run, and overrides the Dockerfile's `CMD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't add this as a comment because i don't have the reputation so it will have to be an answer instead.

I am new to Docker myself so I am not sure why it is stalling but when you specify the port with `-p 80:5111` you are mapping port 5111 in the container to port 80 on the Docker host.

So you should connect with `http://localhost:80/swagger` instead.

Comment: Thanks - I switched the ports and it works fine now